# Помогите с запросом на объединение, уникальность, случайность и ограниченность

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица покупок:

```
Pokupki (
Pokupka int,
Person int,
Pokupka_set int, 
Pokupka_date Date)
```

Есть таблица групп товаров, учтенных в предыдущей таблице

```
Sets (
Pokupka_set int,
Tovar  int
)
```

Понятно, что товаров в одном наборе - много...

Вопрос - как выбрать случайно N количество товаров и покупок в которые они входят, так чтоб товары не повторялись?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял условие, то обычный join/left join и distinct что бы не было повторяющихся записей

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.Tovar, p.Pokupka
FROM Sets s
LEFT JOIN Pokupki p ON s.Pokupka_set=p.Pokupka_set
```

Comment: Это было бы слишком просто. Нужно чтоб Pokupka_set не рассыпалась

Comment: Попробуйте переформулировать условие задачи, не совсем понял, что значит "не рассыпалась"?

Comment: Нужно выбрать случайные покупки, чтобы товары в этих покупках были уникальны

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю точно можно ли сделать так на sqlserver, но я бы попробовал следующее:

```
SELECT Pokupka 
FROM Pokupki
WHERE Pokupka NOT IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT Pokupka 
   FROM (
      SELECT s.Pokupka, p.Tovar
      FROM Sets s
      JOIN Pokupki p ON s.Pokupka_set = p.Pokupka_set
      GROUP BY s.Pokupka, p.Tovar
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   )
)
```

А случайность, думаю, уже не так сложно получить по полученному множеству.

Решение не самое лучшее, но это первое, что в голову приходит.